# Method is not returning CSV file - Java

Tags: java, file, csv

I am trying to read a  `HashMap` and write to a CSV file. I am using `CSVPrinter`, but my method is not returning a CSV file.

This is the code I use:
**Edited Code**

```
   import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
    import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;

public class SJV{
    public File writeCSV(Map featureSet) throws IOException{

        CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
        Map<String, Integer> map = featureSet;
        File temp = File.createTempFile("tempfile", ".tmp");
        FileWriter fs = new FileWriter(temp);

        CSVPrinter csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fs, csvFileFormat);
        //csvFilePrinter.printRecord(FILE_HEADER);

        csvFilePrinter.printRecord(map.keySet().toArray());
        csvFilePrinter.printRecord(map.values().toArray());



csvFilePrinter.close();
fs.close();


        return  temp;
    }
}
```

This is the test I have:

```
public void testWriteCSV() throws IOException {
    SJV sj = new  SJV();

    HashMap<String, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    hmap.put("Feature1", 1);
    hmap.put("Feature2", 2);
    File fs = sj.writeCSV(hmap);

    if (fs.exists()){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(fs );

        while (input.hasNextLine())
        {
           System.out.println(input.nextLine());
        }
        input.close();
    }
```

I really don't understand why the method is not returning a CSV file.

Comment: A bit of code is missing.  What is `sj`?  Is anything written?  Any errors?

Comment: What is the method returning instead of a CSV file?

Comment: It is retuning an empty file.

Comment: I don't think you're closing the file.

Comment: @SteveSmith  It is another problem but  the real problem is empty file

Comment: @Kumaresp No, actually, it isn't another problem. It is probably the reason for the problem you have. Try correcting it.

Comment: Steve Smith and RealSkeptic are absolutely correct.  I just did a minimal search "CSVprinter api filewriter" and you would be surprised at the number of results I got

Comment: I did it.  Again the problem persists !

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put your new version with the close.

Comment: I think you should do `csvFilePrinter.close();` before `fs.flush()` and `fs.close()` (in fact you don't need those other two, because `csvFilePrinter.close();` will also flush and close `fs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (In this code I have changed the format from .tmp to .csv)

One problem was we were not closing the csvFilePrinter -> csvFilePrinter.close() and what I understood from the question is that the user is expecting a CSV file extension , so , I have used .csv extension while writting it .
:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
    import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;

    public class TestMain {

        public static void main(String args[]) {

            HashMap<String, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            hmap.put("Feature11", 1);
            hmap.put("Feature22", 2);
            CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator(System.lineSeparator());
            Map<String, Integer> map = hmap;
            File temp;
            try {
                temp = File.createTempFile("tempfile", ".csv");
                FileWriter fs = new FileWriter(temp);

                CSVPrinter csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fs, csvFileFormat);
                csvFilePrinter.printRecord(map.keySet().toArray());
                csvFilePrinter.printRecord(map.values().toArray());
                csvFilePrinter.close();

                System.out.println(" temp " + temp);

                if (temp.exists()) {
                    Scanner input = new Scanner(temp);

                    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                        System.out.println(input.nextLine());
                    }
                    input.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

Edited as per the suggestions in comment (This code works for me and here is the sample output) :

```
 temp C:\Users\<MY USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp\tempfile7124969351872886823.csv
Feature11,Feature22
1,2
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to not throw the IOException and do a try/catch on it yourself..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
fs.flush();
fs.close();
csvFilePrinter.close();
```

Comment: There is no need for flush before close. Also no need to close the `FileWriter` before closing the `CSVPrinter` (if `CSVPrinter` has `close()`).

Comment: The `fs.close()` will close fs before anything buffered inside the csvFilePrinter is flushed. Then when you try to close `csvFilePrinter` nothing will happen before fs is already closed.

Comment: you have verified the file is empty, and not merely checking it inside the code, right?